# Excel: Search for text-string in a row, return value of adjacent column cell (columns will differ frequently)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried to use `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, `LOOKUP`, `INDEX` and `MATCH` but haven't so far been able to solve the problem. I want to fill column A with the value adjacent to the value left of STRING that might be found in each row. The column of interest frequently differs.

E.g.
Return value of F1 if G1=STRING, F2 if G2=STRING, E3 if F3=STRING, D4 if E4=STRING

[Picture](http://img42.com/FWO3r+)

Comment: format your cells to see what is your data structure like. provide a screenshot of the data and expected results.

Comment: sorry couldn't upload any image since I am a new user, is the description and example above ok?

Comment: upload to external image hosters like imgur.com and then post the link here.

Comment: I bet you were using the `MATCH` function without the optional 3rd parameter `[match_type]` which if you set it to 0 it should probably work for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by:

**=IFERROR(INDEX($S2:$BJ2, MATCH("STRING", $S2:$BJ2,0)-1),"")**

Now, if I want to extract the 2nd, 3rd and 4th value (if it happens to be more than one match) adjecent to "STRING" which changes have to be made?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your data is in E1 to H100 - adjust as you need.

First we need the row -

```
SUMPRODUCT((E1:H100=A1)*ROW(E1:H100))
```

Then we use the same trick to get the column

```
SUMPRODUCT((E1:H100=A1)*COLUMN(E1:H100))
```

This gives us the row and column of the text
Now we use this to find the text in the next column
As the row and column are offset from cell 0,0 and A1 is 1,1 we need to subtract 1 from the row, and then 2 from the column to make it 1 cell to the left
This leaves us with the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(A1,SUMPRODUCT((E1:H100=A1)*ROW(E1:H100))-1,SUMPRODUCT((E1:H100=A1)*COLUMN(E1:H100))-2)
```

don't forget to anchor points if you go dragging the formula to fill multiple cells

Comment: The one above only returned #NAME?, it worked with: =IFERROR(INDEX($S2:$BJ2, MATCH("STRING", $S2:$BJ2,0)-1),"") but now I am stuck with only the first match.